# ServiceController permissions Windows 2016

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2016

we have a legacy application that recently got deployed on a Windows 2016 instance.  We are encountering access denied errors that we did not see when it was hosted on a Windows 2012 box.

The service account does have permissions to start/stop services.  The one thing we are concerned about is that it is actually a monitor service. Meaning, it is checking to see if the primary app running under a different service is processing data properly from a queue. If it is having issues, this service will restart it. I am wondering if there were any changes in Windows 2016 that changed the access profile. Nothing has changed with the code in years.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated

> **Error**

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32 desiredAccess)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
   at DacMonitor.Monitor.StartService(String serviceName, Int32 timeoutMilliseconds)
```

Code:

```
   public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        Log.Info(string.Format("Going to attempt to restart service: {0}", serviceName));
        try
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            Log.Info(string.Format("Stopping service: {0}", serviceName));
            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped &&
                service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
            {
                service.Stop();                    
            }

            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

            // count the rest of the timeout
            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

            Log.Info(string.Format("Starting service: {0}", serviceName));
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(string.Format("Error trying to restart the service: {0}", serviceName), ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We found that we ultimately needed to give the user account admin credentials. There may have been some additional permissions that we could have given the account to try and get it to work, but decided at least for now just to give it those rights.